# Cordova - Emulate [platform] builds fine, but fails within the app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I've converted an Angular 5 project into Cordova project.

When I run `cordova emulate browser`, my application works great.

How ever, when I try to emulate it on Android or iOS it builds fine, but it fails within the application.

Android Error:

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/vendor.2f2a0573c67e0d8a78d3.bundle.js: Line 1 : ERROR
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/vendor.2f2a0573c67e0d8a78d3.bundle.js (1)
```

iOS Error:

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
```

I noticed that if I remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.5bc80649598bbc3df9fa.bundle.js"></script>
```

There won't be any error, but my app obviously won't load since it's compiled JS is in that file.

What could be causing this problem? I'm sure that it's an issue in configuration or permissions, as the app works fine in browser.

On Android I tried adding

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="120000" />
```

to `config.xml` but it didn't give any improvement.

Comment: Rather than convert the project, you should create a brand new Cordova app, then manually import index.html and the relevant files, testing on device as you go. The so-called "browser" platform is as good as opening index.html in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your error (-1100) mean: **NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist**

I think you try to get that file from wrong location.

Try to check path structure in generated filesystem assets or with web inspector and check if file is there:

```
file:///android_asset/www/vendor.2f2a0573c67e0d8a78d3.bundle.js
```